# Polymer 1.0 - Responsive columns

Tags: polymer, flexbox, polymer-1.0, responsiveness

Here is what I want to achieve with Polymer Elements:

[Polymer Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dTDAl.png)

The column size is not always the same width but relative to the screen or warpper-div size. In example 1, it's each 16.66%, in example 2 it is 33.33%, in example 3 it should be 100%.

I need a responsive layout where -dependent upon the screen size- a different number of columns is displayed per row and each of their column sizes will be adjusted.

Does anyone know how I can achieve this with https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-flex-layout? I am a little puzzled on how to work with `flex` and `layout horizontal`/`layout vertical`.

I would be very thankful for a codepen (or similar) example on how code and result could look like.

**Update**: I found the solution here: [How to control number of items per row using media queries in Flexbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31621257/how-to-control-number-of-items-per-row-using-media-queries-in-flexbox)

Comment: For example, I tried to add for @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
        .flex-6 {flex:1!important;}
    } I thought this would overwrite 1/6 flex and make it 100% flex. Didn't work...

Answer (score 0):

You can use [iron-media-query](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-media-query) to set a property on an element, apply clsses to HTML elements depending on this property value and then apply different CSS depending on the set classes.

Comment: I think roughly I have an idea what you mean but it would be great if anyone could provide an example. I think you also mean the @apply approach in custom styles that I didn't really get. More precisely, I have no idea how to set the maximum number of columns per row.

Comment: Yes `@apply()` is usually how `iron-flex-layout` is used.
I only know how to technically implement what I explained above. I haven't done anything with flex-layout itself yet though. It probably helps if you add concrete code/html to your question that shows what you actually try to accomplish.

Comment: That's part of the problem. I made the image to show what I want to accomplish because no one of the x solutions I tried did work out... :(