# Div responsive equivalent in polymer?

Tags: css, html, polymer

In Bootstrap I have this:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-8"></div>
```

But in polymer I only found this:

```
<div class="flex-12"></div>
```

But the `div` not change position is held in the same horizontal line with polymer .

What kind or property need to change his position according to the screen size?

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems similar to this one: [Polymer 1.0 - Responsive columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34838465/polymer-1-0-responsive-columns)

The author there found her solution here: [How to control number of items per row using media queries in Flexbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31621257/how-to-control-number-of-items-per-row-using-media-queries-in-flexbox)

Basically you'll need to write a bit more css, but the solution is to add `@include max-width` in your code and then change the flex-basis depending on the width.