# Unordered List with fixed items number columns using pure CSS

Tags: html, css, multiple-columns, listitem

Let's I am creating an unordered list using jQuery from JSON. I want to make sure, however long the list is, that my list contains columns of five. Doesn't matter how many columns. Just that it's columns of five.

Example:

```
1st item    6th item
2nd item    ...
3rd item    ...
4th item
5th item
```

I have to mention that the order doesn't really matter to this particular use case.

Comment: If you're using JavaScript anyway, why not use JavaScript to put each group of 5 items in an inline-block element.

Comment: Did you mean that you would like to display five (5) columns with an unlimited number of rows?

Comment: How is everyone having trouble understanding this? Just read. He obviously wants **5 items per column** for an arbitrary number of items -not 5 columns.

Comment: @canon You are correct sir. It's as I described.

Comment: @KonstantinosDimakis You can use flexbox like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29546550/how-to-force-a-flex-box-to-display-4-items-per-row). It's simple and css only, but it will work only in modern browsers. I'm not going to do any example.

Comment: Not sure if something like this could be solution: https://jsfiddle.net/w1rg7x9v/ Problem: you have to set fixed height for list items and container...

Comment: @nevermind yes that solution occurred to me, but I didn't want to set fixed height. Thanks though :)

Comment: why cant you use column-count:5

Comment: this link could be helpful to you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31621257/how-to-control-number-of-items-per-row-using-media-queries-in-flexbox

Comment: @Geeky column-width + height would do , but even then flex is more ... flexible.  http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/LbWrrd Problem , op do not want to set a fixed height. So CSS on itself is not an option :(

Comment: @Geeky if you **actually read** the OP's question and look at his sample output, you'll see that he's not looking for a pre-defined number of _columns_. He's looking for a pre-defined number of _rows_ across an arbitrary number of items/columns.

Comment: If it's not possible, then by all means answer it's not possible. But please be certain of your answer.