# Angular flex-layout with ngFor

Tags: css, angular, typescript, flexbox

I am very new to flex-layout and having trouble fixing the following:

https://github.com/angular/flex-layout

My ngFor:

```
<div fxLayout.xs="column">
 <country fxFlex *ngFor="let country of countries" [country]="country"></country>
</div>
```

Result:

[image]

What If I only want 3 countries on a row, in other words what if I want the last 'Germany' to be on the next row?

Is this only possible by creating multiple **fxLayout**'s? By that I mean 2 loops, 1 to create the number of **fxLayout**'s and another inner loop to show my country components (**fxFlex** items). Thanks in advance!

Comment: What happens if you put `min-width: 33%` on each box? In standard flexbox, it will ensure only 3 items max are on a row

Comment: fxLayout is probably a Angular 2 Directive.
Please provide the resulting(jsfiddle.net) HTML and CSS which appear in the browser.

I know the solution for this situation.

Comment: Update:
Indeed, it's a Ng2 Directive(https://github.com/angular/flex-layout).
I'll make some tests tomorrow with it so I can provide the answer using its methods.

Comment: @Marian07 It is indeed Angular 2, thanks in advance for you example!

Comment: @ChristopherMoore min-width does not work :S

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I found the solution on: [How to control number of items per row using media queries in Flexbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31621257/how-to-control-number-of-items-per-row-using-media-queries-in-flexbox)

HTML:

```
<div fxLayout="row" fxLayout.xs="column" fxLayoutWrap="wrap">
  <country fxFlex.gt-xs="50%" [fxFlex.gt-md]="regularDistribution" *ngFor="let country of countries" [country]="country"></country>
</div>
```

Typescript:

```
//I use this to show of expression bindings in flex-layout and because I don't want the calculated value in the HTML.
regularDistribution = 100 / 3;
```

> wrap: multi-line / left to right in ltr; right to left in rtl

The key here is the **fxLayoutWrap="wrap"**

Answer (score 10):

With angular 6 and new version of flex-layout my code looking like this:

```
<div fxLayout="row wrap">
   ...
</div>
```

Comment: Just throwing this out there, If you aren't dynamically changing the layout, this can be simplified to `fxLayout="row wrap"`