# Angular Flex-Layout Grid Line Break with fxLayoutWrap

Tags: html, angular, angular-flex-layout

I used to be able to create a grid with line break in angular flex-layout using fxLayoutWrap.

Seems that it doesn't work anymore. Whatever number I put in fxFlex, the div doesn't go to the next line. I saw the example [Angular flex-layout with ngFor](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42212846), but I can't make it work on my side.

```html
<div fxLayout="row" fxLayout.xs="column" fxLayoutWrap="wrap">
  <div 
    fxFlex.gt-xs="50%" 
    [fxFlex.gt-md]="regularDistribution" 
    *ngFor="let country of countries">{{ country }}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure Angular flex-layout is still the best way to work on grid layout. I'm wondering about going back to Bootstrap.... which means calling back jquery in an Angular Project .... :(

Comment: no chance I'm going back to Bootstrap. There must be a way to have 
line break in a grid with flex-layout

Comment: What version of flex-layout are you using? As far as I know fxLayoutWrap directive has been deprecated in 6.0.0-beta.16. You would need to add it as a second argument at  fxLayout="row wrap"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downgraded     "@angular/flex-layout": "2.0.0-beta.10-4905443",
in package.json and it's working again...