# Angular Flex-layout with ngFor, X elements per row

Tags: angular, angular-flex-layout

I tried to follow this post [Angular flex-layout with ngFor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42212846/angular-flex-layout-with-ngfor) to do what I want but I can't make it.

I have this code:

```html
<div *ngFor="let room of listRoom;">
  <div class="room">
    Room {{room.label}}
    <div *ngFor="let bed of room.beds;">
      <div class="bed">
        Bed #{{bed.label}}
        <button mat-raised-button color="accent" (click)="assignThisBed(bed)">
          Assign this bed
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My `listRooms` contains usually between 10-15 elements
and I'd like to have 3 rooms on a row then breakline, 3 rooms, ...

Can someone help me? Thanks..

Here is a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mufat4?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) with my code.

Comment: It's pretty well explained in the first answer. What is the error/problem you run into?

Comment: If i do smthg like this :
 <div fxLayout="row" fxLayout.xs="column" fxLayoutWrap="wrap">
  <div fxFlex.gt-xs="50%" [fxFlex.gt-md]="regularDistribution" *ngFor="let room of listRoom; let i = index;">
    Room {{room.label}} ......
  </div>
</div>
It just doesnt work. I have only one line with all rooms. I guess I'm doing wrong

Comment: Stackblitz, plz

Comment: I see no flex layout here....

Comment: I edited with stackblitz link

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code (derived from the other SO question) is not working because `fxLayoutWrap` is deprecated according to the [changelog of Angular Flex-layout](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#500-beta13-2018-02-22). Instead, you should set it directly to the `fxLayout` attribute to take effect:

```html
fxLayout="row wrap" fxLayout.xs="column wrap"
```

is the outcome. I also add a percentage sign to the `regularDistribution` variable: `100 / 3 + '%'`.

```html
<div fxLayout="row wrap" fxLayout.xs="column wrap">
  <div fxFlex.gt-xs="50%" [fxFlex.gt-md]="regularDistribution" *ngFor="let room of listRooms;" class="room">
      Room {{room|json}}
  </div>
</div>
```

[Here's an updated StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-e1kp6x?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) that solves your issue. If the viewport is larger than `fxFlex.gt-md`, it will show three items per row.

Comment: He wants to show every 3 rooms in a line. you'r result is not like that !!!

Comment: @Arash It is, if the screen is bigger than media query `md`.

Comment: thanks a lot, exactly what i was looking for !! thanks!